# Sorting almost sorted array with a minimum heap

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, sorting, heap

I'm currently looking into the quickest way to *sort an almost sorted array*:

> Given an array of \$n\$ elements, where each element is at most \$k\$ away
>   from its target position, devise an algorithm that sorts in \$O(n \log k)\$
>   time.

I've implemented a sorting function which "slides" through an input list, pushes the element from a sliding window into a min heap (using the [`heapq` built-in module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html)), pops the minimum element which is collected in the `result` list:

```
from typing import List
from heapq import heappush, heappop


def sort_almost_sorted(a: List[int], k: int) -> List[int]:
    if not a:
        return []

    length = len(a)
    if k >= length:
        return sorted(a)  # apply built-in "timsort", designed to be quick on almost sorted lists

    result = []
    min_heap = []  # maintain a min heap for a sliding window
    for slice_start in range(0, length, k + 1):  # sliding window
        # push the next slice to min heap
        for index in range(slice_start, min(slice_start + k + 1, length)):
            heappush(min_heap, a[index])

        result.append(heappop(min_heap))

    # put the rest of the heap into the result
    for _ in range(len(min_heap)):
        result.append(heappop(min_heap))

    return result
```

It works on my sample inputs.

Do you think I'm using the minimum heap appropriately and this implementation is \$O(n \log k)\$? What would you improve code-quality or code-organization wise?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the logic for which this is \$O(n log k)\$ instead of \$O(k^2)\$, can you elaborate?

Comment: @ChatterOne the idea was based on the min heap's "log k" complexities for pushing and popping the min element, but I think I am overcomplicating a bit, looks like I can simply push the next element to the heap instead of using this "sliding window"..and I may be not using the heapq correctly, cause the built-in sorted outperforms this approach dramatically on the artificial almost sorted lists I've prepared. Well, feedback would be definitely helpful. Thanks.

Comment: If they're at most `k` away, you can probably split the list in sublists of `k` elements and sort those. I'm not sure how to exploit this fact though.

Comment: I think you've almost got it sorted: you need a sliding window, but you _don't_ need to rebuild it all the time. First read the first 2k items from the list into a heap. Then, iterative over the remaining elements, each time adding the next element to the heap, and then removing the minimum of that element from the heap and putting it in a new array. When you run out of elements, you just heap the heap out into the output. This means that your heap is never larger than `2k+1` (giving `O(log(k))` add and pop), and you always consider each element in the context of those k either side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Algorithm complexity

I am not 100% sure, but it looks like a fancy heapsort which runs (after all) in \$O(n \log n)\$. In order to get this intuition, consider

```
for slice_start in range(0, length, k + 1):  # sliding window
        # push the next slice to min heap
        for index in range(slice_start, min(slice_start + k + 1, length)):
            heappush(min_heap, a[index])

        result.append(heappop(min_heap))
```

You operate in chunks of length `k + 1` array components (save for the very last chunk that may be shorter). For each chunk, you load it entirely to the heap, and then ***pop only one element*** from it to the result array. Finally, in

```
for _ in range(len(min_heap)):
        result.append(heappop(min_heap))
```

you handle the majority of elements via heap sort, and that's linearithmic worst case running time.

## Perhaps this one?

```
# This sort runs in O(n log k + k log k),
# which simplifies to O(n log k) whenever k = o(n)
# (k is sublinear in n).
def window_heapsort(a, k):
    if k > len(a):
        return sorted(a)

    window_width = k + 1
    window_heap = []
    result_array = []
    index = 0

    # Initialize the window heap:
    # Runs in O(k log k)
    for i in range(window_width):
        heappush(window_heap, a[i])

    # Keep sliding the window over the array:
    # Here, the size of the heap alternates between
    # 'window_width' and 'window_width - 1', which is
    # O(k), and thus pops and pushes run in O(log k).
    # Since we march over (at most) n elements, the
    # complexity of this loop is O(n log k).
    while index + window_width < len(a):
        result_array.append(heappop(window_heap))
        heappush(window_heap, a[window_width + index])
        index += 1

    # Dump the leftovers to the end of the result array:
    # Runs in O(k log k)
    while window_heap:
        result_array.append(heappop(window_heap))

    return result_array
```

You can find the entire test snippet [here](https://gist.github.com/coderodde/e1f85e1ffdbe8b4aafb947365f461097). Hope that helps.